# Software Engineering - Time Schedules, Projects Estimates

Tags: project-management, software-design

My question is how someone can really estimate the duration of a project in terms of hours?
This is my overall problem during my carreer.
Let's say you need a simple app with customer/orders forms and some inventory capacity along with user/role privileges.

- If you'd go with Java/Spring etc you should have X time.

  If you'd go with ASP.NET you should have Y time.

  If you would go with PHP or something else you would get another time

  right?

  All say break the project in smaller parts. I agree. But then what how do you estimate that the user/role takes so much time? 
  The problem gigles up when you implement things that let's say are 'upgraded' ( Spring 2.5 vs Spring 3.0 has a lot of differences for example ).
  Or perhaps you meet things that you can't possibly know as it is new and always you meet new things!Sometimes I found odd behaviours like some .net presentation libraries that gave me the jingles! and could cost me 2 nights of my life for something that was perhaps a type error in some XML file...

  Basically what I see as a problem, is that there is no standardized schedule on that things? A time and cost pre-estimated evaluation? It is a service not a product. So it scales to the human ability.
  But what are the average times for average things for average people?

Answer (score 3):

We have lots and lots of cost estimation models that give us a schedule estimate, COCOMO 2 being a good example. although more or less as you said, a type error can cost you 2 nights. so whats the solution
in my view

- Expert judgement is serving the industry best and will continue to do
  so inspite of various cost estimation techniques springing up as the
  judgement is more or less keeping in mind the overheads that you
  might have faced doing such projects in past
- some models give you direct mapping between programming language LOC
  per function point but that is till a higher level and does not say
  what if a new framework is intorduced (as you mentioned, switching
  from spring 2.5 to 3.0)
- as you said, something new keeps coming up always, so i think thats
  where expert judgement again comes into play. experience can help you
  determine what time you might end up working more.

so, in my view, it should be a mix of estimation technique with a expert judgement of overheads that might occur with the project. more or less, you will end up with a figure very near to your actual effort.

Answer (score 3):

My rule of thumb is to always keep the estimation initially language agnostic. Meaning, do NOT create different estimations for different implementation languages. This does not make sense, as a client will express to you requirements, in a business sense.

This is the "what". The "how" is up to you, and the estimate given to a client should not give the choice to them. The "how" is solely your domain, as an analyst. This you will have to arrive upon, by analyzing the demands of the business, then find what experiences you have in the teams, your own time constraints, your infrastructure and so on. Then deliver an estimate in BOTH time, and the tech you assume you will use.

Programming languages and algorithms are just mediators to achieve business need. Therefore the client should not be deciding this, so you shall only give one estimate, where you as an analyst have made the descision on what to use, given the problem at hand and your resources.

I follow these three domains as a rule:

The "what" - Requirements, they should be small units of CLEAR scoping, they are supplied by the client

The "how" - Technical architecture, the actual languages and tech used, infrastructure, and team composition. Also the high level modeling of how the system should integrate and be composed (relationship of components), this is supplied by the analyst with help of his desired team

The "when" - This is your actual time component. This tells the client when to expect each part of the "what". When will requirement or feature x be delivered. This is deducted by the analyst, the team AND the client together based on the "how" and "what" together with the clients priorities. Usually i arrive at the sums based on what the team tells me (technical time), what i think (experience) and what the client wants (priority). The "when" is owned by all stakeholders (analyst/CM, team and client).

The forms to describe the above can vary, but i usually do high level use case-models that feed backlogs with technical detailing. These i then put a time estimate on, first with the team, then i revise with the client.

The same backlog can then be used to drive development sprints...

Answer (score 1):

Planning / estimation is one of the most difficult parts in software engineering.

Then:
- Split the work in smaller parts
- Invite some team members (about 5-8),
- Discuss what is meant with each item
- Let them fill in a form how many hours each item is, don't discuss or let them look at others
- Then for each item, check the average and discuss if there is a lot of variance (risks?)
- Remove the lowest and highest value per item
- Take the average of the rest

This works best for work that is based on experience, for new projects with completely new things to do it is always more difficult to plan.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Micheal hello, you speak I think from employer perspective. The think is that the last 4-5 years, most of the time I am alone in what ever project my company has done. No co-workers. No above me at all except a company-manager-salesman. The problem is that always hunt me for the time on one hand. First I have a feeling and becomes an inner question for me why they still have me? And second comes up to me, how can I measure something like that ?

Comment: In that case the best is to plan your work in short pieces, like something in hours or a few days. Afterwards, check how much time it REALLY costed, then plan the next piece and use the multiplication factor of the difference of the previous piece you planned.

Comment: E.g. you plan for the first task 12 hours, and it took really 18, when you plan the next part for 7 hours, use 7 * (18/12) = 10.5 hrs ... Most people (including me) are too positive about planning (mostly takes longer than expected). You will get a better factor after some time probably, also the factors can change for the type of work, like design, code, bug fixing (this one is tricky).

Comment: I see your background is C#, as you mention in the profile, how would you estimate a simple then site, with user/role privileges and a form customer, a form orders and a form inventory of material ( BOM ) in order to bring it that on asp.net site. editable ones and a report of orders...from the perspective of an average engineer? would be good for 30 days with docs also, uml diagrams perhaps, database design and tests?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't give you a clear answer, most because I don't have much experience in office automation. It mostly depends on the quality of requirements, your experience in such software, etc.

Comment: ok Michel, after the discussion we had I will keep the 'factor' thing, it's very smart approach. While I hope more to offer their experience in the discussion, I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no short easy answer to your question. Best I can do is to refer you to a paper which discusses some of the different models and techniques used for cost analysis.

[Software Cost Estimation - F J Heemstra](http://doc.utwente.nl/2151/1/Heemstra92software.pdf)